# How to select a button in React Native, without selecting others?

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components, react-functional-component

I have a simple quiz app that always has the same answers, with different points to each one.

When USER presses, I want the button to be selected, change color, pass the id to a state.
When USER presses another, I want to de-select the first button and select this instead.

Using React functional components, ReactHooks, styled-components and TypeScript.

the buttons:

```
<AnswerButton
  id="1"
  isSelected={isSelected}
  style={shadow}
  onPress={handleAnswer}
>
  <AnswerText>Muito Correto</AnswerText>
</AnswerButton>


 <AnswerButton
      id="2"
      style={shadow}
      isSelected={isSelected}
      onPress={handleAnswer}
    >
      <AnswerText>Moderadamente Correto</AnswerText>
    </AnswerButton>
```

styled-components:

```
    export const AnswerButton = styled.TouchableOpacity<AnswerProps>
  background: ${darken(0.05, #EEEDED)};
  border-radius: 35px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;

  border: 2px solid #64007b;

  ${props =>
    props.isSelected &&
    css
      border-color: #c53030;
      background-color: #fff8f7;
      border-width: 2px;
    }
;

export const AnswerText = styled.Text
  color: #64007b;
  font-family: 'RobotoSlab-Medium';
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 30px;

  text-align: center;
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding a state that contains the selected button id

```
const [selectedButton, setSelectedButton] = useState(0)

const handleAnswer = (id) => {
   setSelectedButton(id)
}

return (
    <AnswerButton
       id="1"
       isSelected={selectedButton === "1"}
       style={shadow}
       onPress={() => handleAnswer("1")}
    />
)
```